# Batch ElGamal Scheme

Tags: encryption, elgamal-encryption, elgamal-signature

I know about ElGamal scheme and its key generation, encryption, and decryption methods. I'm not sure about what is meant by batch ElGamal.

Can someone please clarify it. How it differs from ElGamal and what are the attacks possible on that scheme. How do we prevent them?

Comment: Batch ElGamal scheme is the collection of all those processes you mentioned. I don't know about what are the attacks possible and what is the real-implementation usage of it.

Comment: Just to make sure we are talking about the same subject, could you indicate where you have found this "batch ElGamal"? I see something [here](http://insiderattack.blogspot.nl/2014/12/a-digital-signature-batch-verification.html) but ... " An attacker could manipulate adjascent messages so that their changes cancel out in batch verification. This might cause an attack on message integrity getting unnoticed. To prevent this, we need to select a batch of message-signature pairs randomly rather than selecting them sequencially for a single batch. " scared the bj out of me.

Comment: @Venba Our helpful mods are a bit more forgiving than on SO I guess (less workload), thanks for the conversion to comment, CodesInChaos :)